# Ubuntu does not recognise DVD-R and DVD+R

Tags: 14.04, dvd

Someone gave me some DVDs where he burnt some videos on them by himself. My Ubuntu installation does them not recognize at all.

"Normal" commercial DVDs I am able to play. I have no real clue where to start. How can I find out what is on the DVD? What may I miss?

I installed the ubuntu-extras and run css.sh. And as said, most DVDs work...

---

I found out that the DVDs are not finalized

I tried to get the data by using "dd", "ddrescue", "dvdisaster"... nothing worked!

Any suggestions?

Comment: i too am facing the same problem if u get any soltion to this will u be able to inform me about that